# IJCADのVBAで長さ寸法の始点・終点を取り出したい

Tags: vba, ijcad

IJCAD 2017のVBAで開発をしています。
長さ寸法（GcadDimRotated）について聞きたいことがあります。

IJCADで図面上にある長さ寸法を選択した後、寸法の始点と終点（座標値）を知りたいのですが、ヘルプでGcadDimRotateやGcadDimensionクラスをいくら調べても、それらしいプロパティが見つかりませんでした。

平行寸法（GcadIimAligned）クラスにはExtLine1Point、ExtLine2Pointのプロパティがあってこちらでは簡単に取得できるようです。

始点・終点を知る方法がわかれば教えてください。

Answer (score 0):

残念ながら、IJCADのVBAではGcadDimRotateの始点と終点を取得することはできません。AutoCADのAcadDimRotateでも取得できないので仕様としか言えないです。

回避策としては、VBAではなくVB.NetやGRXで開発を進めるとか、取得するだけのモジュールを.Net APIやGRXで作ってVBAから呼び出して使うとか、一時的に長さ寸法を分解（Explode）して得られたLineから始点終点を求めるなどの方法が考えられます。

Answer (score 0):

回転寸法オブジェクトに ExtLine1Point と ExtLine2Point プロパティがないのはおかしいと思います。

回転寸法の始点と終点の座標値は図形リストの13と14で取得できます。

```
(setq el (entget (car (entsel))))
```

座標値を文字列化する関数を用意して

```
(defun ptos ( p ) 
  (strcat (rtos (car p)) "," (rtos (cadr p)) "," (rtos (caddr p))))
```

システム変数 USERS1 に文字列化した座標値を保存して

```
(setvar "USERS1" (ptos (cdr (assoc 13 el))))
```

VBAでそれを取得することも可能です。

```
Dim text As String
text = ThisDrawing.GetVariable("USERS1")
```

また図面に拡張データか拡張レコード(XRECORD)を用意すれば、座標値をLISPとVBAの間で受け渡すことも可能です。